Xcode 15.4 Error: Showing Recent Errors Only Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
In an react native app when I try to build app in Xcode I get following error:
Showing Recent Errors Only
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use    -v to see invocation)
more detailed log:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"\_FIRFirebaseVersion", referenced from:
+\[FIRAnalytics topLevelVersion\] in FirebaseAnalytics\[x86_64\]\[10\](FIRAnalytics.o)
"\_FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
+\[FIRAnalytics observeFirebaseInstallationIDChanges\] in FirebaseAnalytics\[x86_64\]\[10\](FIRAnalytics.o)
"\_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
\-\[APMMonitor isLoggableLevel:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[68\](APMMonitor.o)
"\_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
\-\[APMASLLogger logMessage:logTag:messageCode:withLogLevel:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[12\](APMASLLogger.o)
"\_GULLogError", referenced from:
\-\[APMPersistentDictionary initWithFileName:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[257\](APMPersistentDictionary.o)
\_APMWriteDictionaryToURL in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[257\](APMPersistentDictionary.o)
\-\[APMUserDefaults synchronize\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[311\](APMUserDefaults.o)
"\_GULLogInfo", referenced from:
\___44+\[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[330\](UIViewController+APMScreenClassName.o)
"\_GULLogWarning", referenced from:
+\[APMMeasurement sharedInstance\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMPersistentDictionary objectForKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[257\](APMPersistentDictionary.o)
\-\[APMPersistentDictionary setObject:forKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[257\](APMPersistentDictionary.o)
\-\[APMPersistentDictionary setObject:forKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[257\](APMPersistentDictionary.o)
\-\[APMUserDefaults objectForKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[311\](APMUserDefaults.o)
\-\[APMUserDefaults setObject:forKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[311\](APMUserDefaults.o)
\-\[APMUserDefaults setObject:forKey:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[311\](APMUserDefaults.o)
...
"\_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
\-\[APMMonitor setDebugModeEnabled:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[68\](APMMonitor.o)
\-\[APMMonitor setDebugModeEnabled:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[68\](APMMonitor.o)
\-\[APMMonitor setVerboseLoggingEnabled:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[68\](APMMonitor.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_FIRApp", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_FIRComponent", referenced from:
in FirebaseAnalytics\[x86_64\]\[11\](FIRAnalyticsConnector.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_FIRInstallations", referenced from:
in FirebaseAnalytics\[x86_64\]\[10\](FIRAnalytics.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_GULAppDelegateSwizzler", referenced from:
in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[7\](APMAnalytics.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[5\](APMAEU.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_GULMutableDictionary", referenced from:
in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[35\](APMEExperiment.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_GULNetwork", referenced from:
in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[7\](APMAnalytics.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_GULSwizzler", referenced from:
in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[330\](UIViewController+APMScreenClassName.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTAppDelegate", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$\_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTConvert", referenced from:
\__OBJC_$_CATEGORY_RCTConvert_$\_RNZoomVideoSdk in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[5\](RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RNZoomVideoSdk in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[5\](RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTView", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RNZoomView in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[35\](RNZoomView.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$\_RNZoomViewViewManager in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[36\](RNZoomViewViewManager.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RCTAppDelegate", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RNZoomVideoSdk in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[5\](RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RCTView", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RNZoomView in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[35\](RNZoomView.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$\_RNZoomViewViewManager in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[36\](RNZoomViewViewManager.o)
"\_RCTConvertEnumValue", referenced from:
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKRawDataMemoryMode:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKVideoPreferenceMode:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKReceiveSharingStatus:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKRecordingStatus:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKError:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKAudioType:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RCTConvert(RNZoomVideoSdk) ZoomVideoSDKVideoAspect:\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[3\](RCTConvert+RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
...
"\_RCTPresentedViewController", referenced from:
\___54-\[RNZoomVideoSdkShareHelper shareScreen:withRejecter:\]\_block_invoke in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[25\](RNZoomVideoSdkShareHelper.o)
"\_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
+\[RNZoomVideoSdk load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[5\](RNZoomVideoSdk.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkAnnotationHelper load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[6\](RNZoomVideoSdkAnnotationHelper.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkAudioHelper load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[7\](RNZoomVideoSdkAudioHelper.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkAudioSettingHelper load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[8\](RNZoomVideoSdkAudioSettingHelper.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkAudioStatus load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[9\](RNZoomVideoSdkAudioStatus.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkChatHelper load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[10\](RNZoomVideoSdkChatHelper.o)
+\[RNZoomVideoSdkChatMessage load\] in react_native_zoom_video_sdk\[11\](RNZoomVideoSdkChatMessage.o)
...
"\_kFIRLoggerAnalytics", referenced from:
+\[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:\] in FirebaseAnalytics\[x86_64\]\[10\](FIRAnalytics.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeCannotAcceptTraffic", referenced from:
\-\[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[42\](APMETaskManager.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotFound", referenced from:
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotModified", referenced from:
\___37-\[APMMeasurement retrievePSMResponse\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement(SKAN) handleSKANFetchResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[66\](APMMeasurement+SKAN.o)
\___46-\[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[67\](APMMeasurement+URL.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeUnavailable", referenced from:
\-\[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[42\](APMETaskManager.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusNoContent", referenced from:
\-\[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[42\](APMETaskManager.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\___37-\[APMMeasurement retrievePSMResponse\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\___46-\[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[67\](APMMeasurement+URL.o)
"\_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusOK", referenced from:
\-\[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[42\](APMETaskManager.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\___37-\[APMMeasurement retrievePSMResponse\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[62\](APMMeasurement.o)
\-\[APMMeasurement(SKAN) handleSKANFetchResponse:data:error:\] in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[66\](APMMeasurement+SKAN.o)
\___46-\[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink\]\_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[67\](APMMeasurement+URL.o)
"\_pb_decode", referenced from:
\_apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[78\](apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
...
"\_pb_decode_varint", referenced from:
\_nano_decode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[315\](decoder_common.o)
"\_pb_encode", referenced from:
\_nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[316\](encoder_common.o)
\_nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[316\](encoder_common.o)
"\_pb_encode_string", referenced from:
\_nano_encode_string in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[316\](encoder_common.o)
"\_pb_encode_submessage", referenced from:
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[79\](apmpb_app_property_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[82\](apmpb_audience_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[85\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[88\](apmpb_client_property_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_config in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[91\](apmpb_consent_config_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_default_entry in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[94\](apmpb_consent_default_entry_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_delegation_entry in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[97\](apmpb_consent_delegation_entry_encoder.o)
...
"\_pb_encode_tag_for_field", referenced from:
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[79\](apmpb_app_property_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[82\](apmpb_audience_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[85\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[88\](apmpb_client_property_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_config in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[91\](apmpb_consent_config_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_default_entry in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[94\](apmpb_consent_default_entry_encoder.o)
\_apmpb_encode_repeated_consent_delegation_entry in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[97\](apmpb_consent_delegation_entry_encoder.o)
...
"\_pb_encode_varint", referenced from:
\_nano_encode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[316\](encoder_common.o)
"\_pb_istream_from_buffer", referenced from:
\_apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[78\](apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
...
"\_pb_ostream_from_buffer", referenced from:
\_nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[316\](encoder_common.o)
"\_pb_read", referenced from:
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[78\](apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[78\](apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[81\](apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[84\](apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
\_apmpb_decode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement\[x86_64\]\[87\](apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Configuration:

Mackbook Pro [Apple M1 Pro] [Sonoma 14.2]

Xcode 15.4

Simulator iPhone 15 [17.2]

react [18.2.0]

react-native [0.73.4]

aws-amplify [6.0.17]


I have tried following:

Deleting node_modules and re- running    pod install

Tried Deleting    ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData And various other solutions available online


